# Some thoughts about documenting an Azure Storage data model

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm looking for a way to document my Azure Storage architecture.

I have a database, so i've made a Data Conceptual Model. This document is printed and pinned on my wall, just above my screens, and that's great.

But what about my Azure storage blob and tables ? How to do the same ?

I've tried to make a xmind graph:

[image: Xmind graph]

But it was finally wasn't a good idea (not very convenient)

I finally did a Excel file :

[image: Useful Excel file]

One big 'line' for Blobs, and another one for the tables.
First column is the base url, 
Second column the 'container' name (or table name), 
Third column the 'template path' (explaination on how the path is constructed), 
Last column an example.

I find this way useful, because you can easily and visually construct the full url, by reading the columns from left to right.

The template path for tables is more tricky, so, I just wrote here the type of object stored, and how are constructed the PartitionKey and RowKey.

If any of you have a better way to do that, or want to share his thoughts about it, it would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How you capture and visualize a schema depends a lot on what your goals are. If you are at the design stage of development and are trying to communicate a data model then I have always found Domain Models to be very useful (typically modeled using UML Class diagrams). Sparx has a nice tool for managing complex domain models. It doesn't sound like this is your problem though as you have already modeled and implemented your domain model - so now it sounds more like you are just looking for a "cheat sheet" of some sort to capture storage types and examples of usage etc - in which case I imagine Excel is as good as anything else.

Jason